# PMF and variance

Tags: probability, random-variables

two fair three sided dice are rolled simultaneously. let X be the sum of two rolls. calcilate PMF(probability mass function) and variance of X.

If any body has solved examples link on the topic of discrete random variables including probability mass function and expected value and variance. please help me. So that I may be able to better understand the beginning questions of these topics as I m new to prob

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if we are expected to assume the dice have numbers $1$, $2$, $3$ written on their faces. For the probability mass function of $X$, we need to calculate $\Pr(X=k)$ for all possible values of $k$. There values are $2$ to $6$.

Suppose one die is red and the other green. Record the result of a toss as an ordered pair $(u,v)$ where $u$ is the number on the green, and $v$ the number on the red. There are $9$ equally likely possibilities,

We get $X=2$ if we get $1$ on red and $1$ on gree. So $\Pr(X=2)=\frac{1}{9}$. We get $X=3$ if we have $1$ on green and $2$ on red, or the other way around. So $\Pr(X=3)=\frac{2}{9}$.  Continue.

For $E(X)$, the mean of $X$, we need to calculate
$$2\Pr(X=2)+3\Pr(X=3)+\cdots+6\Pr(X=6).$$

But there is a simpler way. Let random variable $U$ be the number on the green, and $V$ the number on the red. Then $X=U+V$ and therefore $E(X)=E(U)+E(V)$.

It is easy to see that $E(U)=E(V)=2$, so $E(X)=4$. We could also show that $E(X)=4$ by a symmetry argument.

For the variance of $X$, we can proceed from the definition of variance, or, somewhat more simply, from the fact that $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. Note that 
$$E(X^2)=2^2\Pr(X=2)+3^2\Pr(X=3)+\cdots+6^2\Pr(X=6).$$

A much nicer way is to note that since $U$b and $V$ are independent, the variance of $U+V$ is the sum of the variances of $U$ and $V$. These can be computed quickly.